# Limit inserting to database based on a different value in a different column

Tags: php, mysql

So, im trying to make a basic reservation system, but i cant make a proper check. Which should go like this, checks if theres any spots available at a certain date (selected from a form), and if a spot is available, check if the time is available. But the time check doesnt work, and allow inserting multiple times. I do date check with
    `if(mysqli_num_rows($checkdate) > 23)`
And tried to check the time with
    `if(mysqli_num_rows($checktime) > 3)`

`$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($checktime);
if($row['laikas'] == $time)`
and
`$row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($timecount);
if($row2 == 4)`
and here is the whole snippet

```
$checkdate = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT data FROM stalai WHERE data = '$data'");
$checktime = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT laikas FROM stalai WHERE laikas = '$time'");
$timecount = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stalai WHERE laikas = '$time'");
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($timecount);
echo "$row2[0]<br>";
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($checktime);
if(mysqli_num_rows($checkdate) > 23)
{
    echo "date exists<br>";
} else {
    echo "date empty<br>";
    //if(mysqli_num_rows($checktime) > 3)
    //if($row['laikas'] == $time)
    if($row2 == 4)
    {
        echo "time exists<br>";
    }
    else {
        echo "time empty<br>";
```

All of this might not make sense, it took a while to write.

Comment: Just a suggestion in terms of working with PHP Date/Time. Always convert your data into the `date` format. Without it, you may end up having the code work randomly. I am saying this as I have experienced this myself.

Comment: Yeah, store date and time as a single entity

Comment: Changed date and time into a single column in the database, and works, and another question, how would i go about checking 1 hour ahead of already existing, so you wouldnt be able to put 15:01 if 15:00 is in use.